# My reCAPTCHA Enterprise site key says "Key Status: Incomplete" then offers no information on how to complete it

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

I created a new site key with Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise for my company's website and it said "all you need to do is finish setting up your key.  Follow the instructions above to do so."  There were no instructions though and the status indicator for my site key says "incomplete."  How am I supposed to complete my site key?  I copied the key into the site key field in my google captcha extension on my website admin page, but there was no secret key given this time to replace it with, so the old secret key is still there.  What do I need to do to finish the site key?

I tried to set up the Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise for my website and ended up with nothing but problems and an incomplete site key.  I was expecting seamless instructions but was left wanting.

Answer (score 1):

Incomplete in this case means specifically that your reCAPTCHA key has been used to [create tokens](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-web-pages) using the `grecaptcha.enterprise.execute` function, but these tokens have not yet been used to [create an assessment](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-assessment) and therefore determine if the traffic was desirable or not.

Note that in reCAPTCHA Enterprise you no longer need a secret key. See more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key).

However it is common when integrating with third-party applications (such as CMS) that the generated reCAPTCHA keys are non-Enterprise, and therefore they would include a secret key as well. Here is how you can identify the secret key when you are in the Google Cloud console https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key#find-key